# Изображение из текстового файла

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, есть изображение допустим jpg которое открыто при помощи блокнота и данный текст скопирован в другой текстовый документ и сохранен как jpg. Вопрос почему изображение не открывается как исходное? Как возможно данное изображение считать из текста? И если использовать побайтное чтение и запись из сохраненного текстового файла тоже не получается.

Comment: сравните по байтам два документа (не в текстовом редакторе, конечно, а чем-нибудь типа "Hex View" в Far'e или кодом) - и увидите

Comment: Понял спасибо. Нашел различия сейчас попробую еще раз считать файл побайтово.

Comment: Текстовый редактор мог добавить [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Маркер_последовательности_байтов) в зависимости от кодировки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ответ в интернете на свой вопрос с сервиса:
https://halluphigh.wordpress.com/2010/08/26/extracting-a-jpeg-image-from-any-file-using-c/

В этом коде используются магические числа для обозначения начал и конца файла для jpeg это 0xFF и 0xD8 не сложно найти и для других форматов брал отсюда:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

сам код ответа:

```
/Remove the excess data in given file and returns the new location of the modified file and
 //returns an empty string if no file was created.
public static string StripExcessDataFromJpeg(string fileLocation)
{
    //if no image is found in the file, it will return this error message
    string newFileName = "";
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileLocation, FileMode.Open));
    try
    {
        bool done = false;
        long count = 0;
        //The file must be read until the end of the file (in which case there was no image)
        //or until the jpeg file is found.
        while ((count < br.BaseStream.Length) && !done)
        {
            //has to be read one at a time so not to consume more than needed
            count++;
            if (br.ReadByte() == 0xFF)
            {
                count++;
                if (br.ReadByte() == 0xD8)
                {
                    done = true;
                    newFileName = fileLocation + ".jpg";
                    WriteJpegBinaryToFile(newFileName, br);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File format not found.");
        //File name set back to empty to indicate the file wasn't created.
        newFileName = "";
    }
    br.Close();
    return newFileName;
}
private static void WriteJpegBinaryToFile(string fileName, BinaryReader br)
{
    FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName);
    //write back the jpeg header already consumed in the stream
    byte[] jpegHeader = { 0xFF, 0xD8 };
    fs.Write(jpegHeader, 0, jpegHeader.Length);
    long count = 0;
    while (count < br.BaseStream.Length)
    {
        long bytesToRead = 1024; //Read 1kb at a time, increase if dealing with larger files.
        if (bytesToRead + count > br.BaseStream.Length)
        {
            bytesToRead = br.BaseStream.Length - count;
        }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesToRead];
        br.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        count += bytesToRead;
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    fs.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Текстовый редактор может игнорировать не печатные символы, то есть ASCII коды которых меньше 32, за исключение перевода строки и табуляции. 
Скорее всего он не копирует их в буфер.

Используйте для копирования части файла какой-нибудь бинарный редактор.